# Gravity forms use cookie to hide form div

Tags: forms, cookies, show-hide, gravity-forms-plugin

Gravity form can create a cookie when the user submits the form. I would like to use this to hide the gform_wrapper div and replace it with a simple message "You have already filled out the form."

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'set_form_1_complete_cookie' );
```

This is a version of what I would like to do that uses Jquery-cookie I tested it independently and it works fine but I can't figure out how to implement something like this with my form.

```
   // when clicked on “X” icon do something
  $('.close').click(function() {
    // check that “X” icon was not cliked before (hidden)
    if (!$('.change-message--on-click').is('hide--first')) {
      $('.change-message--on-click').removeClass('hide--second');
      $('.change-message--on-click').addClass('hide--first');

      // add cookie setting that user has clicked
      $.cookie('hide-after-click', 'yes', {expires: 7 });
    }
    return false;
  })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.